# How to get 'Log On As' information from local Windows Services

Tags: c#

From what I can see 'ServiceController' doesn't have the option to pull the 'Log On As' information from local Windows Services.

Currently I'm using ServiceController to provide me with the Display Name of the service and the current status but I would also like to pull in the 'Log On As' information too.

I did see wmic can get this information from startname using:

```
wmic service get name,startname
```

Currently this is my code:

```
public string GetLocalServices()
        {
            var sc = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController();
            ServiceController[] svcList = ServiceController.GetServices();

            try
            {
                foreach (ServiceController service in ServiceController.GetServices())
                {
                    string serviceDisplayName = service.DisplayName;
                    string status = service.Status.ToString();

                    var serviceDetails = "Display Name: " + serviceDisplayName + "Service Status: " + status + "\r\n" + "\r\n";
                    File.AppendAllText(Path.Combine(_TempPath, @"LocalServices.txt"), serviceDetails.ToString());
                }
                return "Retrieving Local Services Information complete.";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return string.Concat("!!! Exception: Unable to gather information on local services ", ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Is anyone aware of how I can query wmic in this class and append this to the serviceDetails variable so I can print out the Log On As information too?

Comment: You just want the user account that the service is running as? Does [Environment.UserName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.username) not meet your needs?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take a look at the WMI code creator tool from microsoft(link below to download). This tool gives you the snippets of code in C# for what you are looking for.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8572

Click on the link to see an image of how the tool works.
[WMI Code Creator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kmkiv.png)